# I am trying to chain promises in an async function working with fetch API but it does not work

Tags: async-await, promise, fetch-api

I am building a website which shows you the price of bitcoin in real time using an API .The problem is I am trying to determine if the price is higher or lower so i put the algorithm for this in a third then.
This is my code:

```js
async function pageReload() {
    const showPrice = document.getElementById("bitcoin");
    await fetch('********', options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            let pastValue = parseInt(response["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["8. Bid Price"], 10);
            showPrice.innerHTML = pastValue;
        })
        .then((response) => {
            let pastValue1 = parseInt(response["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["8. Bid Price"], 10);
            let current = null;
            if (current > pastValue1) {
                current = pastValue1;
                console.log('e mai mare');
            } else if (current == pastValue1) {
                current = pastValue1;
                console.log("e egal");

            } else if (current < pastValue1) {

                console.log("current este " + current + ' pastValue este' + pastValue)
                current = pastValue1;
                console.log("e mai mic");
                showPrice.style.color = 'red';
            }
        })


    .catch(err => console.error(err));



}

const timer = setInterval(pageReload, 20000);
setInterval();
```

[image]

[image]

At first I put the algorithm in the second then but both variables were getting same numbers instead of 'current' getting the number before.
This is the error I am getting from browser:
[image]

Comment: Code related to your question should be pasted into your question as text, not as an image.  This allows it to be indexed, searched, copy/pasted into answers, used more easily by the visually impaired, read more easily on a small screen, etc...  And, it just generally easier to deal with.  Your task when asking a question here is to make it easy for people to understand and then supply an answer.  Putting all your code in images is not doing any of that.  Please use the "edit" link to fix your question.

Comment: In addition, I'd suggest you also clarify exactly what you're asking for help with.  So, far all you've really said is that there's a problem in the third `.then()` when something is supposed to be higher than something else.  Please be a lot more specific.  Use the variable names in your description.  Refer to specific lines of code.  Tell us exactly what result you got and what result you were expecting.

Comment: Also, add any results from debugging or troubleshooting you've already done.  What was the value of `response` that you got.  What `console.log()` statements have you inserted and what did you find?

Comment: If you fix your question as described above, I can supply an answer.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. It s my first time using stackoverflow. So the pastValue variable contains the price of btc in real time while the current variable contains the number inside pastValue after it has been updated ( e.g pastValue = 5(now current variable is null)  then pastValue contains 7(now the current should be 5) )

Comment: also i put the code inside the question

Comment: OK, I was writing an answer, but I don't see how you expect the `current` value to work.  You do this `let current = null` and then you compare `pastValue` to `current`.  That will never generate a different outcome because you're just comparing to `null` every time.  Can you describe what this is supposed to accomplish?  What is `pastValue` supposed to be and what is `current` supposed to be?  Are you intending to save one of these values from one call to the next so you really are comparing to a prior computed value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    let pastValue = parseInt(response["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["8. Bid Price"], 10);
    showPrice.innerHTML = pastValue;
})
.then((response) => {
    let pastValue1 = parseInt(response["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["8. Bid Price"], 10);
    let current = null;
    if (current > pastValue1) {
        current = pastValue1;
        console.log('e mai mare');
    } else if (current == pastValue1) {
        current = pastValue1;
        console.log("e egal");

    } else if (current < pastValue1) {

        console.log("current este " + current + ' pastValue este' + pastValue)
        current = pastValue1;
        console.log("e mai mic");
        showPrice.style.color = 'red';
    }
})
```

You have to either `return response` from the first `.then()` here in this section of code or you have to just get rid of the second `.then()` here since it isn't needed as there's no asynchronous operation in this first `.then()`.  Because you aren't doing a `return response`, then when you try to do this:

```
parseInt(response["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["8. Bid Price"]
```

`response` will be `undefined`.

In addition, your value of `current` is ALWAYS reset to `null` to you then compare `pastValue` with `null` which will always give you the same result.  I'm guessing that you want `current` to be retained from one call to the next so you can compare to that.  To do that, you have to declare it outside this function so it survives from one call to the next.

It's also substantially simpler to not mix `await` and `.then()`.  If you're using `await`, just use it instead of `.then()` and use `try/catch` instead of `.catch()`.

Here's what I would suggest:

```
// declare current here so it is retained from one function call to the next
let current = 0;

async function pageReload() {
    try {
        const showPrice = document.getElementById("bitcoin");
        let response = await fetch('********', options);
        let data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        let pastValue = parseInt(data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["8. Bid Price"], 10);
        showPrice.innerHTML = pastValue;
        if (current > pastValue) {
            console.log('e mai mare');
        } else if (current == pastValue) {
            console.log("e egal");
        } else if (current < pastValue) {
            console.log("current este " + current + ' pastValue este' + pastValue)
            console.log("e mai mic");
            showPrice.style.color = 'red';
        }
        current = pastValue;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

const timer = setInterval(pageReload, 20000);
setInterval();
```

It also seems like you're missing some logic inside your if/elseif/elseif because all they are doing except for the last one is just doing a `console.log()`.  Don't you want to be doing something to modify the page in those if/else branches?

Comment: thanks you helped me very much! I want the price shown on the page to be green if the price is higher but I didn t wrote that in the code because at first I wanted to see if it works( that s why I wrote only console.log in the first 2 statements)